# How to find number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of all unordered pairs $\{A,B \}$ of subsets of an $8$-element set, such that $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $\left |A  \right | \neq \left |B  \right |$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my original answer where I misread the question.  It gives the number of pairs of subsets $\{A,B\}$ in which $A \cap B=\emptyset$ and $|A| \neq |B|$.  Fortunately, we can use it to answer the desired question.

Since $\{A,B\}$ is unordered, and $|A| \neq |B|$, we can introduce the symmetry breaking condition $|A|<|B|$.  So the number of pairs of subsets $\{A,B\}$ in which $A \cap B=\emptyset$ and $|A| \neq |B|$ is
$$
\sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=i+1}^{8-i} \binom{8}{i} \binom{8-i}{j}
$$
where $i$ accounts for the size of $A$ and $j$ accounts for the size of $B$.  We do the bookkeeping:

$$
\begin{array}{r|cccc}
  & j=1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
i=0 & 8 & 28 & 56 & 70 & 56 & 28 & 8 & 1 \\
1 & - & 168 & 280 & 280 & 168 & 56 & 8 & - \\
2 & - & - & 560 & 420 & 168 & 28 & - & - \\ 
3 & - & - & - & 280 & 56 & - & - & - \\
\end{array}
$$

This sums to $2727$.

This can be verified computationally using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
Number(Combinations(Combinations([1..8]),2),P->Intersection(P[1],P[2])=[] and Size(P[1])<>Size(P[2]));
```

---

Getting to the desired answer:

- The number of ordered pairs of subsets $(A,B)$ with $A \neq B$ is $(2^8)^2-2^8$ (subtracting for the $A=B$ cases).  We divide by $2$ to get the number of unordered pairs: $$\tfrac{1}{2}((2^8)^2-2^8)=32640.$$

  This can be verified with the GAP code:

  ```
  Number(Combinations(Combinations([1..8]),2),P->P[1]<>P[2]);
  ```
- The number of unordered pairs $\{A,B\}$ with $|A|=|B|$ and $A \neq B$ is $$\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sum_{i=0}^8 \binom{8}{i}^2\right)-2^8\right)=6307.$$  (There are $\binom{8}{i}^2$ ordered pairs $(A,B)$ with $|A|=|B|=i$; we subtract those with $A=B$, and divide by $2$ to get the unordered number.)

  This can be verified with the GAP code:

  ```
  Number(Combinations(Combinations([1..8]),2),P->Size(P[1])=Size(P[2]) and P[1]<>P[2]);
  ```

These numbers can be used to give the desired answer: the number of unordered pairs $\{A,B\}$ such that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $|A| \neq |B|$ is $$32640-6307-2727=23606.$$

This can be verified with the GAP code:

```
Number(Combinations(Combinations([1..8]),2),P->Size(P[1])<>Size(P[2]) and Intersection(P[1],P[2])<>[]);
```

Comment: +1, and BTW, in GAP one can use `Number(...)` instead of `Size(Filtered(...))`

Comment: (Oh, I should know that.)  I updated my answer.

Comment: Hello Rebecca J. Stones$\sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=i+1}^{8-i} \binom{8}{i} \binom{8-i}{j}$ means that you have selected $i$ objects for $A$  and then from remaining $8-i$ objects you are selecting $j$ objects for $B$. But this means that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ . But question says $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$

Comment: You're right!  I'm sorry about that; I misread the question.

Comment: Very nice Rebecca J. Stones